# When a ConcurrencyException occurs, what gets written?

Tags: concurrency, ravendb

We use RavenDB in our production environment. It stores millions of documents, and gets updated pretty much constantly during the day.

We have two boxes load-balanced using a round-robin strategy which replicate to one another.

Every week or so, we get a ConcurrencyException from Raven. I understand that this basically means that one of the servers was told to insert or update the same document within in short timeframe - it's kind of like a conflict exception, except occurring on the same server instead of two replicating servers.

What happens when this error occurs? Can I assume that at least one of the writes succeeded? Can I predict which one? Is there anything I can do to make these exceptions less likely?

Comment: What do you mean by your servers being load-balanced: sharding or FailoverBehavior.ReadFromAllServers?

Comment: Do you use optimistic concurrency?

Comment: @Idsa: I mean they're hosted on Azure VMs in a load-balanced set. We have made no specific decisions about concurrency, so I guess we see the default behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ConcurrencyException means that on a single server, you have two writes to the same document at the same instant.

That lead to:

- One write is accepted.
- One write is rejected (with concurrency exception).

Comment: "at the same instant" - probably more accurate to talk about a window rather than an instant. I assume that window is the period between loading a document and then saving it?

Comment: Also, is it correct to assume that in the case of two near-simultaneous modifications to the same document, the first write succeeds and the second results in the ConcurrencyException?

Comment: Same instance means, the same instant as far as the server is concerned. That is, the second write happens after the first one happened, but before the transaction committed. 
Another way to get this error is if you are using optimistic concurrency, in which case your description is accurate.

Comment: I still don't think I have an answer to the question of which write wins. I'm assuming the first?

Comment: The first as far as the server is concerned, yes